# ndarray display with scrolling cpabilities in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, numpy-ndarray, vscode-debugger

Does anyone know how to display, in Visual Studio Code, a NumPy ndarray like an Excel sheet with scrolling capabilities?

I've searched VSC extensions but found nothing.

The closest match was [vscode-numpy-viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Percy.vscode-numpy-viewer), but I must save the array to be able to view it.

Also, it misses 2 things

1. does not show current index (line and col in a bidimensional array)
2. we can only scroll down, so the view gets a bit confusing for large arrays

I would like to have an Excel like viewer.

Comment: Hi Jorge, any update of this issue, have you checked the posted answer? :)

Comment: I can't use Jupyter due to code complexity. Sorry for not having replied.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using jupyter extension to see your data:

1. Install [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).
2. Create the `.ipynb` file and put your python script in the jupyter cell.
3. Run the cell and click **Variables button** on the top of the window.

[image]

4. You could see the array in the jupyter tab. VsCode will open a Data Viewer tab for you if you double-click the array.

[image]

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks, but I can´t use Jupiter due to code complexity.